# mysql IN() with wrong return

Tags: mysql

This is my first question, and I1m not sure if Im doing something wrong...

Im working with MYSQL.

The problem is

IN (10,12) returns the values that I want

IN ('10,12') returns only the first value

I think I have the "second" situation on my recordset

How to "fix" it in one select query?

PS: This is my query. 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(gcr.descricao) FROM grupos_contas_relacional gcr WHERE id IN (gce.relacionados)

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is here. Can you post some sample data, along with expected and actual results?

Comment: What is your schema for the table and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(gcr.descricao) 
FROM grupos_contas_relacional gcr 
WHERE find_in_set(id, gce.relacionados)
```

#### But you should actually better change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Or better yet fix the schema